# setRoot does not work after using SDK

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, amazon-cognito, angular-fullstack

Ionic version:
[ ] 3.X

Current behavior:
In my Application I have three options for login AWS Cognito Identity Provider , Google , facebook.
After successful login authentication when user moves to the Drivesetup Page, I set the Drivesetup Page as a root page (setRoot) but I'm facing a problem that user can easily go back again on login screen using mobile back button.

Expected behavior:
I am expecting that user can't go back to the login page by pressing mobile back button when I'm using setRoot to navigate the screen from login to dashboard.

Steps to reproduce:
Code Included.

GitHub Repo:-
https://github.com/saurabhschauhan/demoApp

Related code:

```
constructor(
    public nav: Nav,
    public app: App,
    public navCtrl: NavController,) {
    }
   this.awsCredentialsService.login(data)
      .then((awsCredentialsServiceResponse) => {
        if (awsCredentialsServiceResponse['status'] == 'success') {
          //navigate page
          this.navCtrl.setRoot('DrivesetupPage');
          //OR
          //this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('DrivesetupPage');
          //or
          //this.nav.setRoot('DrivesetupPage');
          this.toasterService.showToaster(email + `Logged in successfully`);
        } else {
          console.log('any other error');
        }
      })
```

Other information:
I had tried two more options this.app.getRootNav().setRoot('DrivesetupPage') and this.nav.setRoot('DrivesetupPage'); but both are not working for me.

Ionic info:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.13.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.13.0
global packages:
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
local packages:
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
System:
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v6.9.1
npm               : 3.10.8
OS                : Linux 3.16
Misc:
backend : pro
```

Thank you.

Comment: Which page you're currently on? Modal or page or? What is the name of it?

Comment: @Sampath I'm on page named as 'HomePage' in demoApp for login and then setRoot for 'DrivesetupPage'.